# How do I copy a version of a single file from one Git branch to another?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I've got two branches that are fully merged together.

However, after the merge is done, I realise that one file has been messed up by the merge (someone else did an auto-format, gah), and it would just be easier to change to the new version in the other branch, and then reinsert my one line change after bringing it over into my branch.

So what's the easiest way in Git to do this?

Comment: Please note that in the accepted answer, the first solution stages the changes, and the second solution doesn't. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045704/151841

Comment: The most up-to-date answer is `git restore --source otherbranch path/to/myfile.txt` (see explanation in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855504/1498178)).

Answer (score 2247, accepted):

Run this from the branch where you want the file to end up:

```
git checkout otherbranch myfile.txt
```

General formulas:

```
git checkout <commit_hash> <relative_path_to_file_or_dir>
git checkout <remote_name>/<branch_name> <file_or_dir>
```

Some notes (from comments):

- Using the commit hash, you can pull files from any commit
- This works for files and directories
- Overwrites the file `myfile.txt` and `mydir`
- Wildcards don't work, but relative paths do
- Multiple paths can be specified

An alternative:

```
git show commit_id:path/to/file > path/to/file
```

Comment: But wouldn't this overwrite all your changes in the master?

Comment: Yes, it would. But that was the intention of the question.

Comment: Probably obvious, but you need to use the complete filename... Wildcards don't work!

Comment: Is there such handy way to "copy" file from certain commit (not from a branch as shown in this answer)?

Comment: although.. it is also nice way:  git show commit_id:path/to/file > path/to/file

Comment: @Chris Hart Wildcards don't work, but relative paths do. Complete filename not always necessary :)

Comment: remote: git checkout origin/otherbranch myfile.txt

Comment: @user1448031 by pull I assume you mean that the file exists in a remote branch? `git checkout <remote_name>/<branch_name> <file>` should work (`git checkout upstream/foo myfile.txt` should "pull" myfile.txt from a forked repo's source repo into your local on the current branch).

Comment: Is there a way to tell git not to stage the file(s) shown in this way? I just want it to update my working copy, not my index.

Comment: For future sleep deprived people, don't forget the full path to file: `git checkout otherbranch path/to/myfile.txt`

Comment: This solution works great for committed files, but is there a way to copy a working file to a new branch? The dilemma of course is that you're forced to commit or stash the file before you can switch branches. At times I find myself in the middle of coding something and see the benefit of putting the current working version of that file into a different branch.

Comment: @jefflab, per a quick test with v2.3.3, specifying just the relative path is sufficient. Moreover, assuming the directory is the same, at minimum just the filename alone needs to be specified.

Comment: After executing checkout, do I have to explicitly unstage the `HEAD` so that I can re-add and commit to include to my own commit message?

Comment: Using wildcards does work, you just need to wrap them with `''` so they don't get interpreted by the shell.

Comment: This is great, but does not seem to work for deleted files. For example, suppose you have branches `a` and `b` with identical folders `foo/` (and identical folder content): If you delete a file from folder `foo/` on branch `a`, followed by `checkout a foo/` on branch `b` (which has the same file), no changes are applied: the file will remain in place on branch `b`.

Comment: If there are gaps between both branches, will this action create conflicts later on if you merge?

Comment: The alternative is what I was looking for

Answer (score 239):

I would use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) (available since Git 2.23):

```
git restore --source otherbranch path/to/myfile.txt
```

---

Why is this better than other options?

- by default `git restore` modifies files only in the working directory

`git checkout otherbranch -- path/to/myfile.txt` copies the file to the working directory (your files on disk) but also to the staging area. It has the same effect as if you copied the file manually and executed `git add` on it. `git restore` by default changes only the working directory.

To get the same result as for `git checkout otherbranch -- path/to/myfile.txt` you can write `git restore --source otherbranch --staged --worktree path/to/myfile.txt`

- by default `git restore` deletes files from the working directory when they are absent in the other branch

`git restore` can be used to restore the whole folder with `git restore --source otherbranch path/to/dir`. You can do a similar operation with `git checkout` but `git restore` by default will delete files that are absent in `otherbranch`. To get `git checkout` behaviour use `--overlay` option.

For example, if there are fewer files on `otherbranch` than in the current working directory (and these files are *tracked*) without `--overlay` option `git restore` will delete them. But this is a good default behaviour because you most likely want the state of the directory to be "the same as `otherbranch`", not "the same as `otherbranch` but with additional files from my current branch".

To *really* get the same result as for `git checkout otherbranch -- path/to/dir` you can write `git restore --source otherbranch --staged --worktree --overlay path/to/dir`

- `git restore` doesn't use shell redirection to create file (Powershell only problem)

`git show otherbranch:path/to/myfile.txt > path/to/myfile.txt` uses standard shell redirection. If you use PowerShell then there might be problem with text encoding or could result in a corrupt file if it's [binary](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1908) (update: fixed in PowerShell [7.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4&preserve-view=true#redirecting-output-from-native-commands)). With `git restore` changing files is done all by the `git` executable.

Comment: Nice answer. Is there a `git restore` way to copy a file from the source branch to a _new_ file on the target branch? With git show I can do this with shell redirection (`git show otherbranch:path/to/file1.txt > path/to/file2.txt`), but I want to avoid shell redirection for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama not really. And I think there is no big chance of getting it in `git restore` (but who know ;)). This redirection issues are basically Powershell problem, not sure if there is any other shell that have problem with it. I usually go back to "git bash" or even "cmd" where I need to use  "`git show` with redirection" commands. Or use GUI like GitExtensions where you can browse file tree of commit and click "Save as" on any file.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't use Powershell so perhaps shell redirection is np for me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Small improvement: better is `git restore --source=otherbranch path/to/myfile.txt` against `git restore --source otherbranch path/to/myfile.txt` the reason is because in the second case, `tab` to list the available branches doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your "post-`checkout`-era" response 

Comment: Which branch should I be located in to run the command ? The destination branch or the source branch ?
I guess the source destination since there's a source option

Comment: FYI the docs say "THIS COMMAND IS EXPERIMENTAL. THE BEHAVIOR MAY CHANGE."

Comment: @qwr yep, but i wouldn't worry too much that it's going to be removed or be changed significantly. `git restore` is suggested when you do `git status`, `git checkout` was replaced in [git tutorials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)  to `git switch` (another "experimental" command). For me it's almost certain that `git restore` and `git switch` are here going to stay, I think git developers are too cautious with these warnings in documentation

Comment: This just copied the current state of my master branch to my new branch, completely discarding the changes in the specified file. Be very careful when running this if you have changes in that file you actually need.

Comment: Worked. In my case I had copy all the changes from other branch. So used "git restore --source otherbranch ."

Answer (score 96):

I ended up at this question on a similar search. In my case I was looking to extract a file from another branch into current working directory that was different from the file's original location. [Answer](http://www.mail-archive.com/git-users@googlegroups.com/msg00256.html):

```
git show TREEISH:path/to/file > path/to/local/file
```

Comment: The intention of 'git show' is to output data to the terminal in readable format, which is not guarantied to match the content of the file exactly. Same as it is better to copy a word-document as a whole, and not try to Copy-and-Paste its content to another document.

Comment: I just wanted to view it so I could compare the contents against the current branch (check some piece of code).
I'd like to use vim with this though... for syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: To compare contents before doing the checkout, `git diff <other branch> <path to file>` works well.

Comment: @Gonen: As of git version 2.21.0, the "git show" manual page says "For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents."  I'm not sure if this means we're always good.  I'm kinda wary to fetch an image that way...

Answer (score 56):

Use the *checkout* command:

```
  git diff --stat "$branch"
  git checkout --merge "$branch" "$file"
  git diff --stat "$branch"
```

Comment: note merge (2nd command) cannot work if the file does not exist on both branches

Comment: Hm. I don't have diffstat. Is that a specific version of a diff tool, because I've never heard of it (and should I switch to it?) :D

Comment: `git diff` supports an `--stat` argument which basically does the same thing as diffstat.

Comment: I had to have both branches checked out locally to get this to work.

Answer (score 36):

1. Ensure you're in branch where you need a copy of the file.

   For example: I want sub branch file in master, so you need to checkout or should be in master `git checkout master`
2. Now check out the specific file alone you want from the sub branch into *master*,

   ```
    git checkout sub_branch file_path/my_file.ext
   ```

   Here `sub_branch` means where you have that file followed by filename you need to copy.

Answer (score 24):

Following [madlep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another/307872#307872), you can also just copy one directory from another branch with the directory blob.

```
git checkout other-branch app/**
```

As to the OP's question if you've only changed one file in there, this will work fine.

Comment: Notice that both the branches need to be properly pulled, first, or use `origin/other-branch` for referring to the repo branch. Basics, but bit me. (the answer is great - no editing required)

Answer (score 6):

Please note that in the accepted answer, the first option **stages** the entire file from the other branch (like `git add ...` had been performed), and that the second option just results in copying the file, but doesn't stage the changes (as if you had just edited the file manually and had outstanding differences).

[Git copy file from another branch without staging it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029523/git-copy-file-from-another-branch-without-staging-it)

**Changes staged** (e.g. `git add filename)`:

```
$ git checkout directory/somefile.php feature-B

$ git status
On branch feature-A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-A'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   directory/somefile.php
```

**Changes outstanding** (not staged or committed):

```
$ git show feature-B:directory/somefile.php > directory/somefile.php

$ git status
On branch feature-A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-A'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   directory/somefile.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: I get "feature-B is not a file", the branch name comes first, about this -> "> directory/somefile.php" may this change the encoding of the file ?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, no one mentioned that before restoring a file
you really want to preview local changes in relation to that branch, so:

```
git diff <other-branch-name> -- <filename>
```

Then when you're accepting a lost (overwritting), you can follow by:

```
git restore --source <other-branch-name> <filename>
or
git checkout <other-branch-name> <filename>
```