# Replace the contents of one directory in GIT

Tags: git

Imagine that I have a repository with directories Dir1 and Dir2 and I am in branchA.

Imagine that I want to get rid of contents of Dir2 and replace them with Dir2 in the master branch, while keeping the content of Dir1.

I don't expect this to be that simple, but ideally :

```
cd Dir2
git [magic that replaces current dir with the contents of master branch]
```

Comment: check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

remove `Dir2` from `branchA` and
fetch it from `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout branchA
$ git rm -r Dir2
$ git checkout master -- Dir2
$ git commit -m "replaced Dir with Dir2 from master"
```

Comment: cool! I was under the impression that you would have to checkout the whole repository. Do you happen to know how to do this in eGit or TortoiseGit ?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with another upstream ? `git checkout notorigin:master -- Dir2`