# Stash just a single file

Tags: git, git-stash

I'd like to be able to stash just the changes from a single file:

```
git stash save -- just_my_file.txt
```

The above doesn't work though. Any alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stash only one file out of multiple files that have changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040833/how-to-stash-only-one-file-out-of-multiple-files-that-have-changed)

Comment: for _single_ file, instead of juggling stash commands, much easier approach is to copy _single_ file and when you want to bring it back to simply copy over the original. eg. `cp just_my_file.txt just_my_file.txt.manualstash`   now you can do all the checkouts and stuff and as the copy is "untracked file", you can move across branches and commits without any problems. When you're on the right branch/commit where you want to "merge the _single_ file" just do `mv just_my_file.txt.manualstash just_my_file.txt` and now you can review changes and commit it where necessary

Comment: @DimitryK Just don't do `git clean -f -d` in the meantime, as it removes untracked files. :-)

Answer (score 265, accepted):

I think `stash -p` is probably the choice you want, but just in case you run into other even more tricky things in the future, remember that:

`Stash` is really just a very simple alternative to the only slightly more complex `branch` sets.  Stash is very useful for moving things around quickly, but you can accomplish more complex things with branches without that much more headache and work.

```
# git checkout -b tmpbranch
# git add the_file
# git commit -m "stashing the_file"
# git checkout main
```

go about and do what you want, and then later simply `rebase` and/or `merge` the tmpbranch.  It really isn't *that* much extra work when you need to do more careful tracking than stash will allow.

Comment: On the upside, you can turn stashes into real branches without a huge pain.

Comment: mixing this with `git checkout tmpbranch the_file` from master makes this extra useful to pull single-file changes back into master branch. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/307872/4692594

Comment: Thank you for using comment prefixes. I wish more people did this when posting commands.

Comment: thanks @pdoherty926 -- readability is a key component to understanding :-)

Comment: What is the benefit of putting comment prefixes?

Comment: It makes it clear what is a command vs the output of commands

Comment: More explicitly: they're not comments, they're command prompts (like the `$` down in the answer below).  Both are routinely used, though sometimes `$` implies a normal user and a `#` implies a root/admin.

Answer (score 579):

If you do not want to specify a message with your stashed changes, pass the filename after a double-dash.

```
$ git stash -- filename.ext
```

If it's an untracked/new file, you will have to stage it first.

However, if you *do* want to specify a message, use `push`.

```
git stash push -m "describe changes to filename.ext" filename.ext
```

Both methods work in git versions 2.13+

Comment: This answer seems the most straight forward to me when making amend changes:

    `git stash -- filename.ext`,
    `git commit --amend`, 
    `git stash pop`

Comment: I think this must rely on some very new functionality.  It doesn't work in git 2.1.4.

Comment: It results in some strange behaviour for me, with the stash being saved, but the same files being added to staging at the same time (git v2.20.1),

Comment: Works with `2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`

Comment: git stash push doesn't exist.

Comment: `$ git stash -m "message" -- filename.ext` works as well (git v2.31.1)

Comment: Doesn't work 2.7.1

Comment: It's not required to stage an untracked file first. `git stash -u -- myuntrackedfile.txt`

Answer (score 68):

You can interactively stash single lines with `git stash -p` (analogous to `git add -p`).

It doesn't take a filename, but you could just skip other files with <kbd>d</kbd> until you reached the file you want stashed and the stash all changes in there with <kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: This takes a long time if you have a lot of files you don't want to stash.

Comment: i don't know when this changed but  as of `git 2.14.1` you can specify file name `git stash -p <filename>`

Comment: Doesn't work 2.7.1

Comment: `git stash -p`  (as well as `git add -p`) skips new files.

Comment: `git stash -p <filename>` does not work for me. Instead, `git stash -- <filename>` worked.

Answer (score 28):

The best option is to stage everything but this file, and tell stash to keep the index with `git stash save --keep-index`, thus stashing your unstaged file:

```
$ git add .
$ git reset thefiletostash
$ git stash save --keep-index
```

As Dan points out, `thefiletostash` is the only one to be reset by the stash, but it also stashes the other files, so it's not exactly what you want.

Comment: Although this keeps the index in the same state, doesn't this also stash the files that are in the index? In other words, if after doing this you commit the index to the current branch, then switch to another branch and do `git stash pop`, isn't it going to apply all of the files, not just the one file that we wanted to stash?

Comment: @DanMoulding: you're absolutely right, I haven't thought about this.

Answer (score 14):

Just in case you actually mean 'discard changes' whenever you use 'git stash' (and don't really use git stash to stash it temporarily), in that case you can use

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

Note that git stash is just a quicker and simple alternative to branching and doing stuff.

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you want to remove all your modified changes to a single file.

Comment: and i would this is the best answer for that particular task

Comment: The question was clear enough and didn't ask how to revert changes to one file. Downvoted.

Comment: @MukulJain I actually needed to use the stash-per-file in a very-temporary fashion (basically separating some changes in two commits that affected the same lines, for one file). I won't actually downvote, just state that it's useless to me.

Comment: Discarding changes is completely different from stashing. This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Just a note to the multiple git "experts" who think the question was clear enough - 8-10 years ago when I was a git beginner and self-learnt git in an adhoc fashion, I associated and only knew the command `git stash` with discarding changes quickly. In fact, I googled the exact title of this post and didn't know I was incorrectly searching.

It looks like multiple people have been in a similar boat and found my answer useful. Think of my answer as a prompt like "Did you mean X". After 8 years, I still stand by my opinion to have this prompt on this page even if I now know git-stash better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, which adds the file in question to the staging area and then simply stashes it:

```bash
git add ./path/file.ext
git stash --staged
```

After that you can do things like roll back all the other changes and bring back the stash afterwards:

```bash
git reset --hard
git stash pop
```