# Copy a directory and all its files from the master branch into a new branch with a different directory structure

Tags: git

Let's say I have a `master` branch and a `gh-pages` branch. The directory structure for master looks like this:

```
projects/
    project-one/
        src/
            app.js
        dist/
            bundle.js
            index.html
    project-two/
        src/
            app.js
        dist/
            bundle.js
            index.html
```

The directory structure for `gh-pages` is blank, but I want it to look like this:

```
project-one/
    bundle.js
    index.html
project-two/
   bundle.js
   index.html
```

I've tried instructions detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another)

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout gh-pages project-one/dist
error
$ git checkout gh-pages -- project-one/dist 
error
```

That should copy the dist folder into the `gh-pages` branch but I get a `error pathspec: file not found` error so I tried `git pull` to sync to the remote, but this does not solve the problem.

Note that in order to make `gh-pages` clean I used `git rm -r` on the whole directory because I do not want `gh-pages` directory structure to be inherited from `master`.

How can I copy everything in each project/dist folder from the master branch into the gh-pages branch?

edit: tried `git checkout gh-pages project-one/dist/**` which gave me a better error msg: `error: pathspec 'dist/bundle.js' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it backwards.  You need to be in the scope of the `gh-pages` branch and *then* do your `checkout` operations:

```
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ git checkout master dir/file1
```

I believe the only way you could copy from a branch to another branch and change directory (without of course doing the manual work after the copy) would be the following:

```
$ git show master:dir/file1 > new_location/file1
```

Comment: Ok thanks, now I know how to copy the files successfully, but the directory structure is still being copied. What if I want to copy and move all files in `dir/**` to the root folder of `gh-pages`? With `$ git checkout master dir/**` the `dir` folder is also being copied into `gh-pages`.

Comment: @Daniel_L perhaps just do a `$ git mv` after the `checkout` operation?  I'm not sure if there's a one-command for this.