# Git: Unable to copy file from one branch to another

Tags: git

I have 2 branches `dev` & `prod`. Would like to copy 1 file from dev to prod.

I'm already on the prod branch on remote server.

So i tried

```
git checkout dev <file-name>
```

If i do

```
git checkout dev -- <file-name>
```

Then it gives

> fatal: invalid reference: dev

Comment: What do you mean by `on remote server`?  Is there some reason why you can't do this work locally?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another

Comment: I have files on server @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I'd recommend that you do the work locally.  With Git typically you do things on your local machine and then push/pull to sync up with the remote server.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen Yes I know that is the best way. But in this situation what we can do?

Comment: Um...do the exact same steps, except do it from your local Git bash?

Comment: Is this a fresh clone? What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: Nope it's not fresh clone. it gives dev & prod branch @ScottWeldon

Comment: And `dev` is on a line by itself, not just e.g. `remotes/origin/dev`?

Comment: HI @ScottWeldon, means `git checkout prod/dev <file-name>`?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but I was asking about the output of `git branch -a`. Please [edit] the output of that command into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need the checkout the other branch and pull down the changes from the server, before trying to get the file from the other branch.

```sh
# checkout other branch
git checkout dev

# pull down changes
git pull

# checkout your working branch
git checkout prod

# checkout file from other branch
git checkout dev -- <file-name>
```