# How to move .gitignore file from one branch to another from commandline

Tags: git, github, branch, gitignore

I have created and pasted a .gitignore file to my master branch, and I want to move it to the hometask_1 branch with the windows 10 command line.

I have used the commands below:

```
git checkout master
git checkout hometask_1 -- .gitignore
```

After the above commands I am getting the following error:

`error: pathspec '.gitignore' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Answer (score 1):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307872/10576762), you can move a file from one branch to another with: `git checkout otherbranch myfile.txt` from the branch where you want the file to end up.

In your case, from the hometask_1  branch, you can run: `git checkout master .gitignore`.