# How to commit a file to only one out of a set of remote repositories without creating separate commits?

Tags: git, version-control

I've a set of remote repositories that I commit the `master` branch to, including GitHub and some private ones.

I want to commit a specific configuration file (with private information) to only one of the private repositories. Aside from that, the commits to be pushed to the remote repositories are identical.

Should I create two branches in order to achieve this, or what's the canonical way?

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing the same branch to multiple repository, then yes, a separate branch dedicated to that one file is preferable, to avoid any mistake.
If that file does not depend on the history of other files, you might even consider an [orphan branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt), to isolate that file in its own branch.

But ideally, you should not push private information, especially in a setup where you are pushing to multiple repositories.

Comment: I need to push a `pip.conf` file to a single repo, since the environment doesn’t allow downloads from official index, and so custom index configuration needs to happen. Suppose I create another branch to host that file. How should I keep the code in both branches identical? I don’t think merge or rebase would work here?

Comment: @Shuzheng Instead of trying to make both branches identical, I would rather, 1/ store the file alone in its branch. 2/ have a builkd script which test for that branch, and, if said branch exists, copy the file to the current working tree. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855504/6309)