# Git remove a file from existing branch to another existing branch

Tags: git

I want to remove a file from existing branch and add it in   another existing branch. For example  I have two branch a and b. I'm in branch a and I want to remove a file a.php from  branch a and add to this file in existing branch b.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a version of a single file from one git branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

First add a.php into branch B:

Checkout branch B:

```
git checkout branchB
```

Checkout file from branchA

```
git checkout branchA a.php
```

Then commit this file

```
git commit
```

Then delete a.php from branchA

Checkout branch A:

```
git checkout branchA
```

Delete the file

```
git rm a.php
```

And commit the deletion

```
git commit
```