# How to get the changes at several files, not all the files, from a commit to local directory?

Tags: git, gitlab

After I git clone the repo, my colleague made a commit which touched several files. The commit is currently in a merge request, not merged to gitlab yet.

I want to retrieve just 2 files from his commit into my local directory, not all the files in the commit. I have the commit hash tag. Can you show me how I should do it?

Comment: Duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307579/how-do-i-copy-a-version-of-a-single-file-from-one-git-branch-to-another
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:
`git checkout remoteName/branchName path/to/file`.

This will basically "copy" over the file to your directory and stage the it. For multiple files you can do `path/to/file1 path/to/file2` instead of the `path/to/file` etc.

Comment: Might also need `git fetch remoteName branchName`.

Comment: If doing a checkout of a remote commit there is no need to do a fetch first. If you do not specify the remote - implying that the commit is available locally and it is not then you might have issues. That's why I included the remoteName in the answer.

Comment: It may be available locally. The question is if it's updated.